# Appending and returning a string

Tags: c++, string, append

I've got a class and one of its functions is to type out some information with the help of previous functions.

```
string printResult()
{
    string result;

    cout<<"\n"<<getName()<<" bla bla bla "<<getPoints()<<" blabla.";

    return result;
}
```

Where getName and getPoints are obviously those other functions.

My question is:
How should I redo/change this part

```
cout<<"\n"<<getName()<<" bla bla bla "<<getPoints()<<" blabla.";
```

to become a string of its own which I can return,with this exact content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `stringstream`

```
#include <sstream>

string printResult()
{
    ostringstream result;

    result<<"\n"<<getName()<<" bla bla bla "<<getPoints()<<" blabla.";

    return result.str();
}
```

Comment: Oh hold on,that worked.Just that I forgot to change elsewhere in the code to get it together.Thanks a whole bunch. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the append() member of std::string:

```
result.append(getName());
result.append(getPoints());
```

Assuming those functions return a string or a char*.

Answer (score 0):

Use stringstream.

Some examples here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/95826-stringstream-tutorial/